# Split a live video stream from a webcam with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, split, stream, webcam, live

I can show the live streaming of my webcam on the screen with the following command:

```
ffplay -f dshow -video_size 1280x720 -i "video = Integrated Webcam"
```

I can also save it in mp4 format in a folder with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video = "Integrated Webcam" -f mp4 "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ ffmpeg \ test \ clips \ out% 02d.mp4"
```

How do I save in the same folder as the 60 second video clips of my live streaming ??
Thanks for your help

Comment: Use the segment muxer to split the video, as shown in the duplicate link.

Comment: Can you write an example??

Comment: `ffmpeg -f dshow -i "video=Integrated Webcam" -f segment -segment_time 60 -reset_timestamps 1 "C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\test\clips\out%02d.mp4"`